# How can I import and use this Java method in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I need to use the **Java method** "getter" of this class:

```
public class GetAyudas {
    public static String[] getter(String correo){
        String[] res;
        if(correo == "pp@gmail.com"){
            return res = new String[]{"Sergio","Durán","Vega"};
        }
        if(correo == "kk@upm.es"){
            return res = new String[]{"Ramón","Y","Cajal"};
        }
        else{
            return res = new String[]{"Nada","De","Nada"};
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getter(args[args.length-1]).toString());
    }
}
```

in Node JS, so I thought that I could **call the main method** with the argument and **save the returned array in the standard output to use it in Node JS** following the next code:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

function getAyudas(email) {
  let args = [];
  args.push("GetAyudas");
  args.push(email);

  let worker = spawn("java", args);
  worker.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    return data;
  });
}

let res = getAyudas("kk@upm.es");
console.log(res);
console.log(typeof res);
```

But it doesn't work: res is undefined. How can I call and use "getter" in a Node JS document ?

Comment: My most encouraging attemp is the one that uses stdout

Comment: maybe put the `console.log(res)` instead of the `return data` (so you have `console.log(data)`)? You cannot return out of the outer function from an inner function.

Comment: In addition, make sure the Java program works on its own, first. It currently contains multiple errors. In Java, comparing strings with `==` is incorrect. Instead, use the `equals` method. Also, calling `toString` on an array does not provide useful output. Use `Arrays.toString(getter(args[args.length-1]))`

Comment: You need a Java program that you can run with spawn that can accept communication from nodejs either in stdin, as an http request or on the command line or some other way and then can communicate back a result, either in stdout, as an http response or via a file or some other mechanism.  You can't directly call a java function from nodejs.

Comment: Do you have the compiled java class `GetAyudas.class` available in the classpath?

Comment: Yes, I have the compiled java class available in the classpath

Comment: jfriend00, the actual project I'm working on has a java method in a class which uses RestController (I think this is the correct name), so I have to call that method from Nodejs and get the returned value. So I think this java program meets requirements, isn't It ?